# The Publish Application In Flutter Can't View Page

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

We have an application that already publish in Google Playstore
Before publish, we have already tested the application to make sure everything is alright
After the application publish, the application can't run, only in splash screen, and then everything is white

[This is what happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLLTQ.jpg)

[This is should application view after Splashscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzpIK.png)

This is application login page

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter_chat_ui/flutter_chat_ui.dart';
import 'package:sipuan_app/latihan/cobacustomlogin.dart';
import 'package:sipuan_app/model/model.dart';
import 'package:sipuan_app/screen/beranda.dart';
import 'package:sipuan_app/screen/launcher.dart';
import 'package:sipuan_app/screen/loadingchatscreen.dart';
import 'package:sipuan_app/screen/registerpage.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  bool lihat = false;
  List<Map> searchResult = [];
  bool circularlihat = true;
  TextEditingController noktp = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController password = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController lupaemail = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
    Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 0.5,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(
    begin: Alignment.topRight,
    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
    colors: [
    Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 128, 167),
    Color.fromARGB(255, 171, 201, 255)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
    Positioned(
    child: Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1,
    child: Stack(children: [
    Positioned(
    left: -MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1,
    top: 0,
                  bottom: 0,
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 238, 27, 143),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  left: -MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1,
                  top: 0,
                  bottom: 0,
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.1,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.1,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 71, 172),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  left: -MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1,
                  top: 0,
                  bottom: 0,
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.2,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.2,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 214, 97, 162),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  left: -MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1,
                  top: 0,
                  bottom: 0,
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.3,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.3,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 235, 167, 204),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  left: -MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1,
                  top: 0,
                  bottom: 0,
                  child: Hero(
                    tag: 'duapuluh',
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.4,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.4,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 235, 175, 196),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
            )),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Positioned(
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 7,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6,
                      child: Image.asset("assets/foto2.png"),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 24,
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      "Login",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 35,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 10,
                        right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 10,
                        top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 20,
                      ),
                      child: Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: const Color.fromARGB(144, 255, 255, 255),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0)),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 10, right: 10, top: 10),
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                    child: Align(
                                      child: ShaderMask(
                                        shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
                                          return LinearGradient(
                                            begin: Alignment.topRight,
                                            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                            colors: [
                                              Color.fromARGB(255, 67, 121, 223),
                                              Color.fromARGB(
                                                  255, 240, 122, 157),
                                            ],
                                            tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
                                          ).createShader(bounds);
                                        },
                                        child: const Text(
                                          "NIK",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 20,
                                              color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                  255, 255, 255, 255),
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        gradient: const LinearGradient(
                                          // Where the linear gradient begins and ends
                                          begin: Alignment.topRight,
                                          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                          // tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
                                          colors: [
                                            Color.fromARGB(255, 67, 121, 223),
                                            Color.fromARGB(255, 240, 122, 157),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0)),
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                      child: TextField(
                                        controller: noktp,
                                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                            disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                            contentPadding:
                                                EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                              vertical: 2.0,
                                              horizontal: 4.0,
                                            ),
                                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                                  topRight: Radius.circular(0),
                                                  bottomRight:
                                                      Radius.circular(0)),
                                            ),
                                            icon: Padding(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                left: 4,
                                                right: 0,
                                              ),
                                              child: Icon(
                                                Icons.email_outlined,
                                                size: 30,
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            filled: true,
                                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                                            hintText: "Ketikan Disini"),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 10, right: 10, top: 10),
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                    child: Align(
                                      child: ShaderMask(
                                        shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
                                          return LinearGradient(
                                            begin: Alignment.topRight,
                                            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                            colors: [
                                              Color.fromARGB(255, 67, 121, 223),
                                              Color.fromARGB(
                                                  255, 240, 122, 157),
                                            ],

                                            tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
                                          ).createShader(bounds);
                                        },
                                        child: const Text(
                                          "Kata Sandi",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 20,
                                              color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                  255, 255, 255, 255),
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                                    child: Container(
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        gradient: const LinearGradient(
                                          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                                          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                          colors: [
                                            Color.fromARGB(255, 67, 121, 223),
                                            Color.fromARGB(255, 240, 122, 157),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                                      ),
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                        child: TextField(
                                          controller: password,
                                          obscureText: !lihat ? true : false,
                                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                                            disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                            contentPadding:
                                                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                              vertical: 2.0,
                                              horizontal: 4.0,
                                            ),
                                            border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                                  topRight: Radius.circular(0),
                                                  bottomRight:
                                                      Radius.circular(0)),
                                            ),
                                            icon: const Padding(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                left: 4,
                                                right: 0,
                                              ),
                                              child: Icon(
                                                Icons.lock_outline_sharp,
                                                size: 30,
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            filled: true,
                                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                                            hintText: "Ketikan Disini",
                                            suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                setState(() {
                                                  if (lihat) {
                                                    lihat = false;
                                                  } else {
                                                    lihat = true;
                                                  }
                                                });
                                              },
                                              icon: !lihat
                                                  ? Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye)
                                                  : Icon(Icons
                                                      .remove_red_eye_rounded),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        vertical: 20),
                                    child: ElevatedButton(
                                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                        primary: Colors.transparent,
                                        onSurface: Colors.transparent,
                                        shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () async {
                                        showDialog(
                                            context: context,
                                            builder: (context) {
                                              return Center(
                                                child: Visibility(
                                                    visible: circularlihat,
                                                    child:
                                                        CircularProgressIndicator()),
                                              );
                                            });
                                        setState(() {
                                          setState(() {
                                            searchResult = [];
                                          });
                                        });

                                        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                            .collection('users')
                                            .where("noktp",
                                                isEqualTo: noktp.text)
                                            .get()
                                            .then((value) async {
                                          if (value.docs.length < 1) {
                                            Navigator.of(context,
                                                    rootNavigator: true)
                                                .pop();
                                            tampilsnackbarverifikasi(
                                                context, "NIK tidak ditemukan");

                                            return;
                                          }
                                          String aaa = value.docs.toString();
                                          UserModellogin bbbb;
                                          value.docs.forEach((user) async {
                                            bbbb =
                                                UserModellogin.fromJson(user);
                                            print("login['email']");
                                            print(bbbb.email);
                                            print("login['email']");
                                            try {
                                              final user = (await FirebaseAuth
                                                      .instance
                                                      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                                                          email: bbbb.email,
                                                          password: password
                                                              .text
                                                              .trim()))
                                                  .user;
                                              DocumentSnapshot userData =
                                                  await FirebaseFirestore
                                                      .instance
                                                      .collection("users")
                                                      .doc(user?.uid)
                                                      .get();

                                              UserModel userModel =
                                                  UserModel.fromJson(userData);
                                              print("objectasdasdas");
                                              print(userModel.verif);
                                              var verif = userModel.verif;

                                              if (verif == '1') {
                                                if (user != null) {
                                                  tampilsnackbarverifikasi(
                                                      context,
                                                      "Login Berhasil");
                                                  Navigator.of(context,
                                                          rootNavigator: true)
                                                      .pop();
                                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                                  Navigator.of(context)
                                                      .pushAndRemoveUntil(
                                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                                              builder: (context) =>
                                                                  loadingpage()),
                                                          (Route<dynamic>
                                                                  route) =>
                                                              false);
                                                } else {}
                                              } else {
                                                tampilsnackbarverifikasi(
                                                    context,
                                                    "User anda belum di verifikasi admin");
                                                FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                                                Navigator.of(context,
                                                        rootNavigator: true)
                                                    .pop();
                                              }
                                            } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                              print(e);
                                              if (e.toString() ==
                                                  "[firebase_auth/wrong-password] The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.") {
                                                print("vdvdjfds");
                                                tampilsnackbar(
                                                    context, "password salah");
                                              }
                                              tampilsnackbar(
                                                  context, e.toString());
                                            }
                                          });

                                          print("login['email']");
                                          print("login['email']");
                                        });
                                      },
                                      child: Container(
                                        height: 40,
                                        width: 200,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            gradient: const LinearGradient(
                                              // Where the linear gradient begins and ends
                                              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                                              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                              // tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
                                              colors: [
                                                Color.fromARGB(
                                                    255, 67, 121, 223),
                                                Color.fromARGB(
                                                    255, 240, 122, 157),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(0)),
                                        child: const Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                              horizontal: 30),
                                          child: Center(
                                            child: Text(
                                              "MASUK",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 50,
                        vertical: 10,
                      ),
                      child: Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: ((context) =>
                                        const RegisterPage()),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                              child: const Text(
                                "daftar akun",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  
}

We have tried to tracking the code and find what is the problem. But until now, we don't know what is the problem.
We expecting the application run smoothly, after splash screen to login page. 
But that happened after splash screen, everything is blank in white.
```

Comment: If you don't mind, can you share the play store link and git repo to analyse the code(if possible)

Comment: this is git repo https://github.com/brojay1406/sipuan and this is playstore link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dpppa.sipuan_app

Comment: @AlexSunderSingh this is git repo github.com/brojay1406/sipuan and this is playstore link play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dpppa.sipuan_app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your project file `lib/screen/loginpage.dart`, you are using `Position` in the child of `SingleChildScrollView` at line no.: 162. You have to remove `Position` widget to solve this.

```
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [...],
              ),
            )
```

Before

```
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Positioned(
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [...],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

I hope this helps..

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works. But i have another problem, the honepage won't show either

Comment: You have to change the same thing in `registerpage.dart(line no.  303)`, `profilpage.dart(line no. 322)`, `homepage.dart(line no. 87)`

Comment: Still you have to remove 3 more `Position` widget as above comment. And let me know if you need help further.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out from your github code is that you are using Firebase and it is a service which requires Internet permission. As in debug mode it will work because the internet permission is added default, but for release version it won't be there.

So, add the below code inside android/app/src/main/Androidmanifest.xml before or after  tag. You can check for reference in debug Androidmanifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I hope it resolves your issue.

Comment: I have already add the permission, but still can't work.

Comment: Did you find out the answer?

Comment: yes, We found the answer. There's unnecessary code in our program. But thankyou very much too, because we found that we forgot to add internet permission